# # Executing ONERROR command at macro ./ram8.do line 3

Tags: model, ram, vhdl

Estoy tratando de hacer una memoria RAM de 8 bits en Quartus 20.1.1 lite pero al querer ejecutar la simulacion de señales me sale este error:
`# ** Error: c:/intelfpga_lite/20.1/modelsim_ase/win32aloem/vcom failed. # Executing ONERROR command at macro ./ram8.do line 3 Error.` 
y no se porque, el programa corre sin ningún error y hace un tiempo todo servía bien.
Ya intenté desinstalar el programa y volverlo a instalar pero aun así el error sigue :(

Este es mi codigo:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ram8 is
generic (DT: positive:=8;
        BI: positive:=8);

port (clk       : in std_logic;
    direcm: in std_logic_vector(DT-1 downto 0);
    x,y,w: in std_logic;
    din: in std_logic_vector(BI-1 downto 0);
    dout: out std_logic_vector(BI-1 downto 0));
    end entity ram8;    
    
    architecture behavior of ram8 is
    type ram8 is array (0 to (2**DT)-1) of std_logic_vector(BI-1 downto 0);
    signal r: ram8;
    
    begin
        process (clk) is begin
            if rising_edge (clk) then
                if x = '1' and y = '1'then
                    r(to_integer(unsigned(direcm))) <=din;
                elsif w= '1' and y='1' then
                    dout<=r(to_integer(unsigned(direcm)));
                else
                    dout<=(others=> 'Z');
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
    end architecture behavior;
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesita hacer estas cinco cosas para la simulación Quartus;

1. Decirle a Quartus que use ModelSim-Altera para las herramientas de simulación (Assignments - EDA Tool Settings - Simulation).
2. Indicar a Quartus que genere un netlist para simulación funcional (Assignments - EDA Tool Settings - Simulation - More EDA Netlist Writer Settings - Generate Functional Simulation Netlist - ON).
3. Indicar a Quartus que utilice VHDL para el netlist de simulación (Assignments - EDA Tool Settings - Simulation - Format for Output Netlist - VHDL).
4. Indicar a Quartus dónde colocar el netlist de simulación (Assignments - EDA Tool Settings - Simulation - Output Directory). Normalmente es la carpeta "simulation".
5. Indicar al simulador (en el simulation waveform editor) que utilice VHDL para el lenguaje del netlist (Simulation - Simulation Settings - Use VHDL).

Eso es lo que debes de verificar al momento de realizar simulaciones con Gate Level Simulator o con University Program Files.